# Adding easytabs jquery plugin to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to add http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/ to the TwentyTwelve child theme
I understand that there is a "right way" to add jquery plugins to Wordpress using
wp_enqueue_script and add action in child themes functions.php

Could somebody provide step by step guide to add this specific plugin, so that I could analyze it and learn from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From: [Wordpress Support Pages](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installing-a-jquery-plugin-into-a-wordpress-install)

Add to **functions.php**

```
/** 
 *  if jQuery not been 
 *  added already
**/
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

/**
 *  Register the script to Wordpress
**/
wp_register_script('easytabs','js/easytabs.js');

/** 
 * Add the Registered script to queue.
**/
wp_enqueue_script('easytabs');
```

You can check if it's worked by viewing your HTML source code within the `<head>` (where `wp_head()` gets called in).

Place the snippet below within the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /** Your code **/ });` add:

```
$('#container-name-for-tabs').easytabs();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Add the file to your theme folder.

```
function include_jquery_easytabs(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
  wp_register_script( 'jq_easytabs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'PATH TO YOUR JS FILE' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jq_easytabs' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery_easytabs' );
```

Add the following snipper to your `footer.php` before the `</body>` tag or to your `header.php` before the `</head>` tag:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('your-target-element').easytabs();
});
</script>
```